# Failed to create swish payment service /. error in configuration in swish payment service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a swish payment service (micro service) however I a encountering en error as

```
(Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildRestTemplate' defined in class path resource [se/challengenow/payment/swish/SwishConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'buildRestTemplate' threw exception with message: Failed to create Swish payment service).
```

I have migrated the project from spring version 2 to v 3 . The Swish configuration code is below

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class SwishConfig {

    private final String keystorePassword;
    private final String keystoreName;

    public SwishConfig(@Value("${cn.keystore.password}") final String keystorePassword,
                       @Value("${cn.keystore.name}") final String keystoreName) {
        this.keystorePassword = keystorePassword;
        this.keystoreName = keystoreName;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate buildRestTemplate() {
        final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        final SSLContext sslContext;
        try {


            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:secret/" + keystoreName);
            FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
            try {
                keyStore.load(instream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
            log.info("init keystore = {}", file.getAbsolutePath());

            // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray())
                    .build();

            final HttpClient client = (HttpClient) HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .build();
            /*final HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .build();*/
            final ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
            final RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                    .errorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean hasError(final ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
                            return !clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleError(final ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {

                            final String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientHttpResponse.getBody()))
                                    .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

                            log.error("Error from swish: {}", result);
                            final String errorCodes = SwishPaymentService.getErrorCodes(result).orElse(result);
                            throw new RuntimeException("For possible error codes (" + errorCodes + ")");
                        }
                    })
                    .interceptors(new LoggingRequestInterceptor())
                    .build();
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
            return restTemplate;

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create Swish payment service", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the stack trace / caused-by output ?

Comment: @PeterMmm what do you mean sir? I have mentioned the error and the code. can you help please